# R >4.1 syntax: Error: function 'function' not supported in RHS call of a pipe

Tags: r, syntax

R 4.1.0 [famously introduced](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) the `|>` ("base pipe") operator and Haskell-like lambda function syntax.

I thought it would be possible to combine the two like this:

```
c(1, 2, 3) |> \(x) 2 * x
```

This fails for me with:

> Error: function 'function' not supported in RHS call of a pipe

I thus assume this is not valid syntax? This works:

```
c(1, 2, 3) |> (\(x) 2 * x)()
```

Is there a more elegant way to chain the pipe and the new lambda functions?

Comment: This tweet here compiles a list of options how the pipe can be combined with lambda functions: https://twitter.com/bmwiernik/status/1398611489901121536?s=09

Comment: What is the rationale for this design decision? (i.e., given that the parser can tell that there is a function in the RHS call of a pipe, why doesn't the parser just assume that we would want to apply the function to the left hand side even without parentheses?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is with curly braces:

```
c(1, 2, 3) |> {\(x) 2 * x}()
```

but this works too:

```
c(1, 2, 3) |> (\(x) 2 * x)()
```

Answer (score 11):

That's the limitation of native pipe. You just include () after the function name, this is different from magrittr.

```r
# native pipe
foo |> bar()
# magrittr pipe
foo %>% bar
```

That is to say, `\(x) 2*x` is equivalent to the old anonymous function syntax `function (x) 2*x`, but similar to named functions,
when used on the RHS of native pipe, you must include ().

Comment: I see - I hoped for an even more concise syntax, but I'm sure the limitations are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another reasonable approach would be:

```r
c(1, 2, 3) |> sapply(\(x) 2 * x)
```

Comment: this is a bad practice. Most of R functions are vectorized by its nature and you should strive to keep this. In your example you force the execution to be applied by individual elements. So eventually decreasing the perfomance of the lambda function you defined