# Using the base R pipe to pipe ggplot2 to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, magrittr

I can pipe from ggplot2 to plotly using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
diamonds %>%
  {ggplot(.,aes(carat, price)) +
      geom_point()} |>
  ggplotly()
```

though I use the magrittr pipe and the base R pipe in the one chain.

Replacing the magrittr pipe with the base R pipe gives:

```
Error: function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

Is there a way to just use the base R pipe?

I found [R >4.1 syntax: Error: function 'function' not supported in RHS call of a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605863/r-4-1-syntax-error-function-function-not-supported-in-rhs-call-of-a-pipe) and https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1229

Breaking the chain avoids the pipe issue:

```
p <- diamonds |>
  ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native R pipe `|>` pipes the LHS into the first argument of RHS. It is important that you need to include the function as a function call, which means adding a `()` at the end of the function name. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
diamonds |> (\(.) {
  ggplot(., aes(carat, price)) + geom_point()
  }) () |> ggplotly()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
(diamonds |>
   ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
   geom_point()) |>
  ggplotly()
```