# Is there a base pipe way of using the unique value of a column to pipe into labs from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipe

The problem is fairly simple - if I take a df and perform a few filtering steps on it, I'd like to be able to pipe the output of those into a ggplot function and use the unique value of a particular column as the title.
Works with the magrittr pipe and curly braces:

```
starwars %>% 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") %>%
  {
    ggplot(data = ., aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = unique(.$species))
  }
```

Doesn't work with the base pipe equivalent:

```
starwars |> 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") |> 
  {
    ggplot(data = _, aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = unique(.$species))
  }

Error in { : 
  function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe (<input>:3:7)
```

Other than assigning the df before calling ggplot, are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Wrap the input in a list having component name . and pass that to `with`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

starwars |> 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") |> 
  list(. = _) |>
  with(ggplot(., aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = unique(.$species))
  )
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use `group_modify`:

```
starwars |> 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") |> 
  group_modify(~ ggplot(., aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = unique(.$species))
  )
```

Comment: nice hack for when we miss the magrittr placeholder!

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
starwars |> 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") |>
  { \(x)
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = unique(x$species)) }()
```

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605863/r-4-1-syntax-error-function-function-not-supported-in-rhs-call-of-a-pipe). Also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe).
The frequently discussed error message:

> Error in { :
> function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe (:3:3)

You might also like to try:

```
Sys.setenv(`_R_USE_PIPEBIND_` = TRUE) 
starwars |> 
  filter(hair_color == "blond") |>
  . => { 
    ggplot(data = ., aes(x = height, y = mass, col = birth_year)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = unique(.$species)) }
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I somehow got overly obsessed with data masking functions.